# d3 not applying class or id

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/yhr2t65t/1/

In the above jsfiddle, I can't give a class or id to the inline "rect" element, and though the js svg applies the appropriate css coloring, it won't apply the .attr for the width.

Similarly, in another project I have a large array which is followed by:

```
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 10000)
  .attr("height", 1000);



var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
 .data(ajaxArray)
 .enter()
 .append("rect")
 .attr("width", 3)
 .attr("height", function(d) {
   return d/30;
 })
 .attr("x", function(d, i) {
   return i*3});
```

All of which displays as expected except that it won't attach to the css class. I've been learning from tutorials but I'm not even sure what to google to find an answer here. I must be missing something syntactically about where or to which elements the .classed selector can be applied? No matter where I add the .class statement, it doesn't work.

Why can't I link my d3 svg elements to a css class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, D3 does apply the classes and IDs properly. Your problem here is something else (actually, a lot of things):

1. You are not selecting the rect you want;
2. Default SVG width is 300px. Your rect is going beyond that;
3. There is no `border` for SVG rects: it's `stroke` instead;
4. Changing classes doesn't have any effect, because in the CSS the ID is more **specific** than the class, and will override it. So, you'll have to remove the ID (or add an `!important` in the class);

Here is a demo. The `rect` doesn't have a `datum` class and it's width is only 50px. After 1 second, the class is added, the ID is removed and the width is changed:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  d3.select("rect").classed("datum", true).attr("id", null).attr("width", 200);
}, 1000)
```

```css
.datum {
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}

#what {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div><svg><rect x="20" y="20" height="100" width="50" id="what"></rect></svg></div>
```

Comment: thank you. but what would be the proper way to select all rects? and why is there a problem overriding the default svg width?

Comment: In that fiddle you linked, you could do `d3.select("#what")`. The classes are being applied to the "enter" selection. Regarding the width of the rect, you won't see anything if you beyond the SVG width.